# Joining Entity Framework tables using Linq when IDs do not exist in both tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Below is a class I have used to generate a table in my database using Entity Framework. I'd like to be able to link this table to another table, `Property`. However, the way my code is set up there is not an Id column in the `Instruction` table, there is a Property property within the class, which then generates a PropertyId column in the actual database, but since the Property property is not an Id I am unable to using Linq to join these tables.

Instruction table

```
[Table("Instruction")]
public class Instruction
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public InstructionTypes InstructionType { get; set; }
        public Property Property { get; set; } //Generates the EF property FK, but is not an ID so therefore cannot be used in linq.
    }
```

Property table

```
[Table("Property")]
    public partial class Property
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address Correspondence { get; set; }
    }
```

Join Query

```
var instruction = 
                from instructions in _context.Instructions
                join properties in _context.Properties on instructions.Property equals properties.Id
                where ...
```

The above query gives a compiler error of: `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.

This error is being generated as I'm attempting to use a property object to join with a propertyId.

How can I alter this query so that I am able to join these two tables?

Comment: `instructions.Property` is of type `Property` which is class. While `properties.Id` is a of `int` type. So you can not simply compare them by using `equals`. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: You already have Property information in Instructions. Whey you want to JOIN?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want to join so that when I pull the Instruction back from the database via its Id I can also pull back the property associated with that instruction. At the moment if I pull back an Instruction I get a null property.

Comment: You need to have proper mapping of `Property` property of `Instruction` class. If you solve that.. you don't need to use JOIN. `Instruction` and `Property` table have PK-FK relationship?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, the database that EF generates maps Property.Id to Instruction.PropertyId, but I do not have access to Instruction.PropertyId from my code as it is represented by the Property class

Comment: @user9754798 can you check in the Database that the Instruction your getting actually has a Property?

Comment: @MindSwipe The instruction does indeed have a Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 99% of all cases, you do not want to use the join operator. Entity Framework automatically generates SQL JOINS for you when you are using Navigation Properties.

```
var instruction = await _context.Instructions.Where(i => i.Property...).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Note, that depending on whether you are using EF6 or EF Core or with different configuration, Lazy Loading may be disabled (if not, I strongly encourage you to disable it as it is a massive performance bottleneck).

So you have to use the `Include` Method to eagerly load the related entity.

```
var instruction = await _context.Instructions.Include(i => i.Property).Where(i => i.Property...).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But before doing this, think if you really need the `Instruction`. If not, your code could become:

```
var property = await _context.Properties.Where(p => p.Instructions.Any(i => ...)).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Please note that you have to extend your `Property` class for this to work to have a back-reference

```
public partial class Property
{
    // No need for the Key attribute, as this is convention
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Correspondence { get; set; }
    public int CorrespondenceId { get; set; } // Not needed in this scenario, but good practice
    public ICollection<Instruction> Instructions { get; } = new HashSet<Instruction>();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write all this out, but I don't understand why I should need to use the above code to solve this issue. The whole point of using EF is so that is automatically generates the relationships and makes it easy to setup and query a database. The code I have written for EF has generated a database with a PK-FK relationship between the Instruction and Property tables. Therefore EF should be able to know about this relationship and pull back the relevant data when I use LINQ.

Comment: I was assuming, you are using code-first, sorry for that. No matter that, the first part of the answer regarding the `Include` still applies.

Comment: `Include` has fixed my problem exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be a newcomer  to linq. As such you are still thinking as if you still are in an sql world.

With linq to entities, the use of `join` is the exception. `SQL join` are generated silently by EF using the navigation properties.

So your query can be:

```
var instruction = 
            from instruction in _context.Instructions                
            where instruction.Porperty.Correspondence.Contains("abc");
```

then you can access

```
instruction.First().Property.Correspondence
```

As a good practice you can delclare the foreign keys as class members and use the fluent API to bind them.

To test you can use the following code,

```
//assuming that Instructions is a DbSet<Instruction>
using (var context = new MyContext() ) {
    context.Instructions.Add(
        new instruction {
            Property = new Property {
                Correspondence = new Address {}
            }
        });
}

using (var context = new MyContext() ) {
    var c = context.Instructions.First();
    console.WriteLine($"{c.Id}, {c?.Property.Id}, {c?.Property?.Correspondence.Id}");
});
```

Comment: I have tried accessing the values of the Property associated with an Instruction like this, however when trying to access Property values I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @tschmitt007 forgot to tag you in the last comment